# Python 3.x - Searching a CSV file for a specific value then printing the row

Tags: python, csv, sorting, search

My task is to read a csv file, find the largest value in the third column and then store the row(s) with that largest value.

So far, I have been able to read the csv file and find the largest value but I am unable to search for that value and get the rows.

```
import csv

with open('file_name.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    ThirdCol = []

#This block takes the 3rd column in the file and makes it a list. After sorting, the last value is the "largest" value.
    for col in reader:
        ThirdCol.append(col['colName']) 
        ThirdCol.sort()
        Largest = ThirdCol[-1]

#This block attempts to take the found largest value and print rows with their third columns matching the largest value.
    for row in reader:
        if Largest == row[2]:
            print (row)
```

I'm not sure what is wrong here, my notebook is giving no output or error messages. I've narrowed down the issue to the "row" section of my code. My intent is to search through the [2] element in the rows, which should be the third column, and print the rows that have a row[2] matching what I determined to be the largest value in the previous for loop.

From other questions on stackoverflow, I'm also thinking my problem may be related to the use of "DictReader" and how in the first for loop I'm searching using strings and the second for loop I'm using an integer.

I'm very new to python, and programming in general. I was only given the link to the [documentation for CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and we have only covered the basic data types, functions and loops. I appreciate any direction anyone can give me, thanks.

Comment: Your `csv.DictReader(f)` buffer is gone once file is closed (outside the `with` block).  I'm surprised it didn't give you a `ValueError`.  You need to execute all your functions in the `with` block.

Comment: Thanks Idlehands, that was a formatting error in the question. I've edited the original post to accurately reflect how I have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('file_name.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # Saving CSV data into a list
    data = [x for x in reader]

# Get maximum value from list using max(list) function
max_thirdcol_val = max([x[2] for x in data])

# Check row by row for 3 col value to max with Max value
for row in data:
    if row[2] == max_thircol_val:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks Uday S. Your code ran but it is outputting only the first row (the column titles). To clarify, if I had a table with [Name, Gender, Age, Income, etc.] I need to find the oldest person(s) and print out the "row" containing their information. For example, I find that the oldest age is 62 and now I need to print all the people that are 62 and their information.

Comment: Disregard the above, the code you provided works perfectly however I overlooked the fact that it was reading my strings as values so when we searched for "max value" it was pulling up the title of the column as having the highest value. Ignoring the first row was sufficient to fixing the issue. Thanks again Uday S.

Comment: @JustinCullum You are welcome. Your approach to the solution is correct, however, you need to explore the functions. if you want to skip the header you have to use next(reader) before making 'data' list. Keep coding, keep exploring, keep helping.